# pandas dataframe columns with non-numeric data get deleted on resample

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas dataframe` with `float` and `object` datatypes.
Before the `resample`...

```
Blended O2 (PPM)                int64
Eng Oil P (PSIG)              float64
Reactor T OUT1 (F)            float64
Reactor T OUT2 (F)            float64
Tank P (Oz/in^2)              float64
Stg1 Scrb P (PSIA)            float64
Active SD                      object
delta                 timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

After the `resample`...

```
Blended O2 (PPM)      float64
Eng Oil P (PSIG)      float64
Reactor T OUT1 (F)    float64
Reactor T OUT2 (F)    float64
Tank P (Oz/in^2)      float64
Stg1 Scrb P (PSIA)    float64
dtype: object
```

When I `resample` the data, the `object` and `timedelta64[ns]` columns get deleted.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

Found it. You must specify `how='first'` else it defaults to the `mean` which can't be done with non-numeric data

```
df = df.resample('1Min',fill_method='ffill', how='first', limit=5)
```